# R Namespace conflcit between plotly and ggplot2 (last_plot)

Tags: r, namespaces, package

I am developing a new r package that has a lot of visualisation in it. The problem occurs when I'm running CMD check. There's a conflict between plotly and ggplot2 for the function `last_plot`.

`Warning: replacing previous import 'ggplot2::last_plot' by 'plotly::last_plot' when loading 'Package'`

Which is normal since I'm using with roxygen:

```
#' @import ggplot2 
#' @import plotly
```

Now I know that I could use `importFrom` or `::` but it would be extremely tedious to list all the ggplot2 and plotly function I used just for one function conflict.

So I would like to know if there is any way to import all function but one (in this case `last_plot`). Is it possible or shall I stick to the good practice with `importFrom` and `::`?

Comment: There is an `except` argument in `import` (see the [official documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports)). Don't know if and how roxygen2 supports it.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine by manually adding the except argument in the namespace. I checked quickly the roxygen2 documentation but haven't seen any `except` argument.